# Executing commands using a jumphost in SSH.NET

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I'm using the SSH.NET library to execute a command on a (Red Hat) server - something like this:

```
var response = string.Empty;
using (var client = new SshClient("<host>", "<username>", "<password>"))
{
   client.Connect();
   var cmd = client.CreateCommand("<some command>");
   response = cmd.Execute();
   client.Disconnect();
}
```

I't works great - except that I have to use a jumphost...

This is normally done by connecting to the jumphost and execute a 'ssh' command to connect to another server:

```
ssh <user>@<server>
```

You are then asked for a password before you get connected. You are now connected to the other server - which is ended by the 'exit' command.

Can this be achieved in SSH.NET (or another C# library) ?

I have tried using the 'RunCommand' which returns:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```